# How insert one item between sorted items SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this :

```
id     name  family  order
861    a     a       1
5241   b     b       2
15     c     c       3
251    d     d       4
.
.
.
541    e     e       9001
41     f     f       9002
8161   g     g       9003
```

When I want get my data I use this query :

`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY order ASC;`

But also I need insert one item between two items with id 861 and 5241. So in this way I need change all orders of all rows.

```
UPDATE users SET order=9004 WHERE order=9003;
UPDATE users SET order=9003 WHERE order=9002;
UPDATE users SET order=9002 WHERE order=9001;
.
.
.
UPDATE users SET order=4 WHERE order=3;
UPDATE users SET order=3 WHERE order=2;
INSERT INTO users (name, family, order) VALUES ('z', 'z', 2);
```

And we know it is very bad idea. Is there a better way?

Comment: I would reconsider the design where the `order` column needs to be updated to insert, but I definitely wouldn't run all of those `update`s individually. Probably more like `UPDATE users SET order=order+1 WHERE order>=2` and then insert.

Comment: Did I read that right... you're actually executing 9k individual update statements?

Comment: I'd prefer to update `order` value for `id=861` to `0` and insert new row with `order=1`. I do not see the reason the least value to be 1 always - this does not effect the ordering result or performance. If such operation is common then I'd prefer also the values to be not adjacent but evenly distributed in the datatype values range, this will simplify such insertion.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is a short query to write. But does this query process heavily? We know this query is good for programmer but is it good for the server? @EdmCoff

Comment: It is just an example and I know it is really bad idea but actually I am looking for good way to do this. the short and easy and light way for programmer and server. @Stu

Comment: The best way is a one-off update along the lines of the answer already proposed. You might consider updating the values to be multiples of 100 or 1000, that way you can insert rows ad-hoc and it won't be an issue.

Comment: @Akina yes. but it is just an example. maybe I want insert item middle of the list... so I need comprehensive and permanent solution.

Comment: The single line update will be _at least_ as "good for the server" as the 9000 individual updates, but if it is a large table I definitely recommend a redesign. Multiplying all the values by 100 (as suggested above) seems good or maybe converting the `order` column to `decimal`.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. I also thought of float numbers like order=2.5. But these methods do not satisfy me. @Stu

Comment: I'm also curious how you're picking the order that gets inserted. Does it come from outside the DB, or could you figure this out from other columns or other tables?

Comment: @EdmCoff It is not solid. I can change anything I want. if two table or more can be helpful tell me. this table and name is just an example. My goal is to add an item to a sorted list.

Comment: *but it is just an example* If you tell this then your model is not adequate. *maybe I want insert item middle of the list...* Have you read the most last sentence of my previous comment? it solves this problem when the amount of rows to be inserted is not high. Of course, it needs in event procedure which recalculates ordering values sometimes and makes the gaps in the values list approximately equal.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE users SET order_c = order_c+1 where order_c >= 2;
insert into users values(123, 'f', 'f', 2);
COMMIT;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd1f6f32579f192149b5c983a28e19d8)

I think the exact was recommended by @EdmCoff ?

Comment: Thanks, yes it is a short query to write. But does this query process heavily? We know this query is good for programmer but is it good for the server?

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
select * from t;
+------------+----------+
| dte        | order_id |
+------------+----------+
| 2018-01-02 |        1 |
| 2018-01-03 |        2 |
| 2018-01-04 |        3 |
| 2018-01-05 |        4 |
| 2018-01-06 |        5 |
| 2018-01-07 |        6 |
| 2018-01-08 |        7 |
| 2018-01-09 |        8 |
| 2018-01-10 |        9 |
| 2018-01-11 |       10 |
+------------+----------+
```

If you want to code and forget consider

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$

create trigger t after insert on t
for each row 
begin
     insert into t1 values (new.dte,new.order_id,null,0);
end $$
delimiter ; 

create table t1 like t;

alter table t1
    add column AI_order_id int auto_increment primary key,
    add column new_order_id int;
alter table t1
    add unique key (order_id,AI_order_id);

truncate table t1;

insert into t1  select dte,order_id, null,0 from t; #bulk load

#select * from t1;

insert into t values (date('2023-05-01'),2),(date('2024-05-01'),2),(date('2024-05-01'),10),(date('2024-05-01'),1);

update t1 join
    (select order_id,AI_order_id, row_number() over(order by order_id,AI_order_id desc) rn from t1) s
    on t1.order_id = s.order_id and t1.AI_order_id = s.AI_order_id
    set new_order_id = s.rn
    where 1 = 1;

update t join t1 on t1.order_id = t.order_id and t1.dte = t.dte
set    t.order_id = t1.new_order_id
where 1 = 1;

select * from t1 order by order_id,new_order_id;

+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| dte        | order_id | AI_order_id | new_order_id |
+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| 2024-05-01 |        1 |          19 |            1 |
| 2018-01-02 |        1 |           1 |            2 |
| 2024-05-01 |        2 |          17 |            3 |
| 2023-05-01 |        2 |          16 |            4 |
| 2018-01-03 |        2 |           2 |            5 |
| 2018-01-04 |        3 |           3 |            6 |
| 2018-01-05 |        4 |           4 |            7 |
| 2018-01-06 |        5 |           5 |            8 |
| 2018-01-07 |        6 |           6 |            9 |
| 2018-01-08 |        7 |           7 |           10 |
| 2018-01-09 |        8 |           8 |           11 |
| 2018-01-10 |        9 |           9 |           12 |
| 2024-05-01 |       10 |          18 |           13 |
| 2018-01-11 |       10 |          10 |           14 |
+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
14 rows in set (0.001 sec)

select * from t  order by order_id;

+------------+----------+
| dte        | order_id |
+------------+----------+
| 2024-05-01 |        1 |
| 2018-01-02 |        2 |
| 2024-05-01 |        3 |
| 2023-05-01 |        4 |
| 2018-01-03 |        5 |
| 2018-01-04 |        6 |
| 2018-01-05 |        7 |
| 2018-01-06 |        8 |
| 2018-01-07 |        9 |
| 2018-01-08 |       10 |
| 2018-01-09 |       11 |
| 2018-01-10 |       12 |
| 2024-05-01 |       13 |
| 2018-01-11 |       14 |
+------------+----------+
14 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```